# How to stop wireless clicker skipping incremental content on slides

Tags: r-markdown, slidy

I like creating my presentations in RMarkdown using slidy.

It seems like Slidy needs to see right and left arrows for moving forwards and backwards through the incremental display of a slide.

It also seems that most remote clickers send Page Down and Page Up.
(Looks like I have a Logitech R400.)

For Slidy, these are causing a jump to the next slide, and is skipping the incremental display of the bullets on my slide.

Is there a way to get Slidy to process the Page Up / Down differently?  To treat them the same as Right/Left?

Also open to any apps that could intercept the clicker and convert it, but that may be better posted in a different community; hoping for a software fix at it's more likely to be portable when presenting on other machines.

Answer (score 0):

Monkey Patch fix :

I went to `self_contained: false` in the `YAML` top-matter, then went to 
`libs\slidy-2\scripts\slidy.js`.

Circa line 2089, found block beginning `if (key == 34) // Page Down`.

Inside that block, found the line `w3c_slidy.next_slide(false);`.
Changed that to `w3c_slidy.next_slide(!event.shiftKey);` (copied from the `Right arrow` block a little further down) and now I get the behaviour I want.

Suspect it may not be robust.  May get trashed when I re-knit the RMarkdown.